# Using The Contents Of A Variable As A Variable

Tags: python

```
variable1 = 1
variable2 = variable1
```

I want to set variable1 to be 5, but I'm getting variable1 from variable2, and I want to somehow set variable2 to act as variable1, so it would look like...

variable2 = 5

but instead of changing variable2 to 5, I want it to act like this

variable1 = 5

I have tried

```
locals()[variable2] = 5
```

but that doesn't work, and neither did

```
exec("%s = %s" % (variable2,5))
```

nor did

```
exec(f"{variable2} = '{5}'")
```

The variables in my code will not be variable1, variable2, etc. The variables will be random, and there will be 20+ of them. 'variable1 = 5' works. I don't want to make a new dict, as I have heaps of other variables assigned, and I need to keep that in locals(). I'm trying to do this, as I want to create an input(), where the person enters a existing variable, and then '5' gets assigned to that variable.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. If you want both variables to point to the same thing, why do you need 2 different names/variables in the first place?

Comment: You said you get variable2 from variable 1, but in the code provided it says `variable2 = variable1`.. So.. you get variable2 from variable1 or...?

Comment: `variable1 = 5; variable2=variable1; variable1 = 1` This does what is required, setting variable2=5 and variable1=1, in one line of code. But idk if this is what youre looking for

Comment: A dictionary is the right data type.  The user inputs a string, which is the key in a dictionary, and then you assign a value to the key in the dictionary.  Don't muck with `locals()` or exec.  In fact, locals() is documented to not necessarily change the local variables and shouldn't be written to, just read.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [dictionary (`dict`)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead.

```
my_dict = {
  1: 5,
  2: 6,
}
print(my_dict[1])
my_dict[3] = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code =>**

variable1 = 1

variable2 = variable1

**You want => change variable1 to 5 but keep variable2 as 1**

**Do =>**

v1 = 1

v2 = v1

v1 = 5

print(v1)

print(v2)

**Output =>**

5

1

**Why =>**

Because we are changing v1 after v2 is set to 1 that means when we make v1 = 5 it does not affect v2 = v1 old value(1)

**Hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
variable1 = [1]
variable2 = variable1
variable2[0] = 5
print(variable1) # prints [5] instead of [1]
```

Here you need to understand the difference between mutable and immutable types in Python. For your requirement you should use a mutable type (e.g. list here). But you were using an immutable type (int) in your code. If you replace it with any mutable type (list, set or dict), it should work as you intended to.

Comment: The problem with this is that it changes both variable1 and variable2, but from what i understand they only want to change variable2, resulting in the change of actually variable1 and not actually variable2

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```py
variable1 = 1
variable2 = variable1

def v2_act_as_v1(x):
    global variable1, variable2

    variable1 = x
    return variable2

variable2 = v2_act_as_v1(5)

print("variable1:", variable1)
print("variable2:", variable2)
```

Output:

```
variable1: 5
variable2: 1
```